# How to insert JSON into cassandra database using java API?

Tags: java, json, cassandra

This is the code I have used for writing my program but there are errors - please give us some suggestions with the corrected code.

```
session.execute("INSERT INTO users JSON '{'id':'user123' , 'age':21 ,'state':'TX'}';");
```

The errors are directed to this one statement so I thought that its not necessary to present the whole code here.TABLE users has already been created in the cassandra database with the columns id, age and state. I could not find any proper answers for  this problem anywhere, I hope my problem is solved here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working query and below java code where I insert it and the results

```
"INSERT INTO users JSON '{\"id\":888 , \"age\":21 ,\"state\":\"TX\"}'";
```

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class CasandarConnect {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    String keyspace = "mykeyspace";

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoints(serverIP)
      .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

    String cqlStatement = "INSERT INTO users JSON '{\"id\":888 , \"age\":21 ,\"state\":\"TX\"}'";
    session.execute(cqlStatement);
   }

}
```

## Result

```
cqlsh:mykeyspace> select * from users;

 id   | age | state
------+-----+-------
 1745 |  12 | smith
  123 |  21 |    TX
  888 |  21 |    TX
```